# CloudKit:Check for subscription locally

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

In wwdc video "CloudKit Best Practices" they mention to check for a line how to "Subscribe to changes". This the code they show:

```
if (subscriptionIslocallyCached) {
    return
}
let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "shared-changes")
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(
    subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: [])

operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = {
    if error != nil { } // Handle the error
    else { self.subscriptionIslocallyCached = true }

}
```

But they don't mention where is define "subscriptionIslocallyCached". Any of you knows how to define "subscriptionIslocallyCached"? or how I need to initialize subscriptionIslocallyCached ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think it's just however you want to keep track of that. UserDefaults is a good way to go.

Comment: @garafajon only use UserDefaults is NOT the answer, iCloud account can change at any given time.

Comment: I only know that you can use NSFileManager's ubiquityIdentityToken to detect account change -- compare current token with the stored version. But you are not recommend to use this approach because it is not supported on all platforms such as watchkit.

Comment: However, CloudKit account API may have a way. I'm investigating.

Comment: Found the answer in WWDC 14, 208.

Comment: @lastcc can you post the solution you found ?

Comment: @user2924482 I think you can detect account change: 1. listen to account change notification 2. detect account change on launch or anytime with fetch current user API.

Comment: @user2924482  may i, have you watched the wwdc video?

Comment: @user2924482 I don't think the above mentioned is a perfect way and I have not put it into practice so I'm not sure either. I'm not using it, and do subscription at launch.

Comment: it's just to ensure you only call once per app launch. there are other ways without the property, such as putting the initialization in didFinishLaunching...